# Sorting alphanumeric data

Tags: sql, database

Hi i want to sort alphanumeric data in ascending order .

data like this : 
**1mac , apple , dom , 007bind , pcworld , 8basic , nothing.**

But here I want the result such as :
**apple, dom ,nothing, pcworld , 007bind , 1mac , 8basic**

can anyone tell me the sql query to show such result.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT your_field FROM your_table ORDER BY (your_field + 0 <> 0 OR your_field = '0') ASC, your_field + 0, your_field
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your database vendor supports such a collation and set the collation accordingly.

http://www.collation-charts.org

E.g. oracle has http://www.collation-charts.org/oracle10g/ora10g.CL8MSWIN1251.GENERIC_BASELETTER.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
select col from sometable where left(col, 1) < '0' or left(col, 1) > '9' order by col
union all
select col from sometable where left(col, 1) >= '0' and left(col, 1) <= '9' order by col
```